# Cant get "Am I sure I want to delete" pop up to not come up when deleting row

Tags: excel, vba, popup, delete-row

I am using the below code to delete a row based on if the value is empty or not.

When running the code - It still pops up asking if I want to delete the data. I don't want that.

```
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Verification Needed")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Text Only")

ws1.Range("A1:H999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=""
ws1.Range("A2:H999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ws1.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    
ws2.Range("A1:F999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=""
ws2.Range("A2:F999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ws2.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Here is the whole code:

```
Sub Tbl_CopyPaste_Verification()

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ChkSht As Worksheet
Dim Chk As Range
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please Select Current Day Report", 
FileFilter:="Excel 
Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
 Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current Day").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    OpenBook.Close
    
End If

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please Select Previous Days Report", 
FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
 Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Previous Days").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    OpenBook.Close
    
End If

Set ChkSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Set Chk = ChkSht.Range("A2")

If Chk = "" Then
 MsgBox ("There is no data to process")
 Exit Sub
Else

Sheets("Verification Needed").Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range("A2:F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range( _
    "VN[[Appointment Start Date]:[Patient Primary Carrier Name]]")
Range("VN[[Appointment Start Date]:[Patient Primary Carrier Name]]").Select

Sheets("Text Only").Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("TO")
Range("TO").Select

Sheets("Text Only").Activate
Sheets("Text Only").Range("A2:F2").Select
Sheets("Text Only").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Text Only").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Verification Needed").Activate
Sheets("Verification Needed").Activate
Sheets("Verification Needed").Range("A2:F2").Select
Sheets("Verification Needed").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Verification Needed").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Verification Needed")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Text Only")

ws1.Range("A1:H999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=""
ws1.Range("A2:H999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ws1.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    
ws2.Range("A1:F999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=""
ws2.Range("A2:F999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ws2.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0


Sheets("Verification Needed").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the deletion and reset to `True` before the end of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

change code as below.

When deleting data, it is the content to select whether to push to the left, push upward, or delete the entire row.

from

```
Range("A2:F999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

to

```
Range("A2:F999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```